# MySQL Triggers, deleting a row after inactivity?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've done some googling but can't really get much relevant information. I'm trying to set a date/time for certain rows to be deleted depending on activity. If active, the time would be bumped to a later time unless activated once again.. Otherwise it will be deleted. I've managed to sort the rows when activated (inserted/updated) in activity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define **active records**?

Comment: Sure. By 'active' I meant one recently updated/being updated. 'Updated' being edited or data being added to the row.

Comment: have you considered running a cron job to delete those inactive rows?

Comment: No I hadn't, good idea though. I'll go try this out now. I could also wait until the row limit is reached (set myself) and then delete those inactive at the lower end of the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly do not put this update/delete in a trigger if you have millions of rows that needs to be deleted you are going to see a huge performance hit on inserts/updates. It is not the best place for it. You can create either a cron job as Filype suggested. Or if you want to keep it all in MySQL use the MySQL Event scheduler.

Go to this page to read more about scheduling events in MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

MySQL Event allows you to schedule things on MySQL on a regular basis.

The code would look something like

```
 CREATE EVENT myevent
 ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
 DO
  DELETE FROM MyTable Where Expired< NOW();
```

Comment: This is great for sessions that you're storing in the database. I'm running this every 15 minutes to clear out old sessions so that we can lock out inactive users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion, I haven't tried yet, you might think to update the row with deleted=1 instead of actually deleting the record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteInactiveRecords AFTER UPDATE,INSERT ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM myTable WHERE updated < (updated-((60)*60*24))
    END;
```

Comment: This won't work. MySQL triggers can't manipulate (DELETE, UPDATE, INERT, …) the tables they are attached to.